# Uncountable chain of negligible sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},m)$ be a (non empty) measure space, with $m$ a complete measure, it's easy to prove that an uncountable union of negligible sets does not need to be negligible or even measurable. But, now, let $(I,<)$ be a totally ordered set ($I\neq \emptyset$ and I not countable) and $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be an increasing family of negligible sets (for $m$) (*ie* $\forall i\in I \ \ m(A_i)=0$ and $\forall (i,j)\in I² \ \ i<j \implies A_i \subset A_j$). Is $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ measurable and $m(A)=0$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega _1$ be the smallest uncountable ordinal equipped with the measure $\mu $  defined on the $\sigma $-algebra of all subsets by
$\mu (E) = 0$, if $E$ is countable,  and   $\mu (E) = \infty $,  otherwise.

Then the set
$$
  \omega _1 = \bigcup_{x\in \omega _1} [0, x]
  $$
has infinite measure despite $\mu ([0, x])$ being zero for all $x$.

---

**EDIT**.
Assuming the continuum hypothesis,  here is an adaptation of the above example for Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb R$.

Choose any uncountable subset $A\subseteq \mathbb R$, and observe that  the cardinality $|A|$ satisfies
$$
  \aleph_0<|A|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}.
  $$
As we are assuming the continuum hypothesis, we deduce that
$$
  |A|=\aleph_1=|\omega _1|,
  $$
so there exists a bijective mapping
$$
  \varphi :\omega _1\to A.
  $$
With an eye on the terminology introduced in the question we take the totally ordered index set $I$ to be $\omega _1$, and for
every $i$ in $\omega _1$, we put
$$
  A_i = \varphi ([0,i]).
  $$
It is then clear that each $A_i$ is countable and hence  negligible relative to Lebesgue measure.

On the other hand,  we have
$$
  \bigcup_{i\in \omega _1}A_i =
  \bigcup_{i\in \omega _1}\varphi ([0, i]) =
  \varphi \left(\bigcup_{i\in \omega _1}[0, i]\right) =
  \varphi (\omega _1) = A.
  $$

Choosing the apropriate $A$ we may now  answer the last two questions posed by the OP.

> Is $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ measurable?

No.  Just choose any non-Lebesgue measurable $A$.

> Must  $A=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ have Lebesgue measure zero?

No.  Just choose $A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Well done, thanks a lot. I was so focused on Lebesgue measure that I did not think at other types of examples. Just an extra question: what about my question for Lebesgue measures?

Comment: I guess Lebesgue measure also presents this phenomenon.  Assuming the continuum hypothesis, we may identify $\mathbb R$ with $\omega_1$, so $\mathbb R$ itself may be writen as an increasing union of countable sets.

Comment: But in this case, I'm not sure we can keep measurability: a well-order on $\mathbb{R}$ is not really compatible with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Countable sets are always measurable.

Comment: Yes of course, but in this case, I don't see how to use your example because the measure you introduced is very different from Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Sure, but here we only need to know that $\mathbb R$ is an increasing union of countable sets.  Incidentally, by the same reasoning any infinite subset of $\mathbb R$ is also an increasing union of countable sets.

Comment: "any infinite subset of R is also an increasing union of countable sets" I agree. But I'm not completely sure that it's possible to extend your example to a Lebesgue measure. I need to think at that more deeply. But it's very interesting, thanks! Moreover, using the continuum hypothesis is tricky and I'm not sure my question is undecidable in ZF :-) ... In fact, I may be mistaken of course, but I didn't see this type of question in a book (maybe in a paper I didn't see?).

Comment: Hold on and I will edit my question to try to  make this clear.

Comment: You don't need the continuum hypothesis, just the axiom of choice. Let $\kappa$ be the least cardinal number such that there is a set $A$ of real numbers of cardinality $\kappa$ which does not have Lebesgue measure zero, and well-order $A$ so that all initial segments have cardinality less than $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for all these answers, Ruy and bof. In fact, this leads me to the following (perhaps trivial?) question: with the same notations as in my initial question, if $|E|=c$ and if $\mathcal{A}'$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and all subsets of E whose cardinal is strictly less than $c$, is it possible to extend $m$ to $m'$ on $\mathcal{A}'$, such that $m'(A)=0$ for all $A\subset E$ with $|A|<c$?